# Where to setup reverse DNS for email server

Tags: reverse-dns

I plan to host my own mail server on a VPS. I understand that I need to set up a reverse DNS entry to prevent commonly used mail services from categorizing my email as spam.
Where should the reverse DNS be configured? On the VPS or on my domain host under the DNS records?

Answer (score 1):

Reverse lookups are on the form of `d.c.b.a.in-addr.arpa.` where `d.c.b.a` represents the IP address `a.b.c.d`.

From this we can see that the zone follows IP addresses, not domain names.

Thus the owner of the IP block (likely your service provider) will have to configure the reverse DNS entry for you.

Answer (score 0):

We had to have our ISP setup our reverse records when we hosted our mail server years back.

Comment: So if I am setting up a mail server on Contabo VPS, I would need to set this up with Contabo?

Comment: Are they supplying the IP(s)?